# CLion does not accept `$(eval include <some file>)`

Tags: makefile, clion

**Question:**

CLion gives an error on the following line in a Makefile:

```
$(eval include <file name>.mk)
```

The GNU Make version CLion points to 4.2.1. The error provided by CLion is

> '!=', $, '(', '+=', ',', ':', '::=', ':=', ';', , , '=', '?=', '`', chars, split, '{', '|' or '}' expected, got 'include'

**Context:**

The reason I need this syntax is because I want to write something like

```
$(foreach MODULE,$(MODULES), \
    $(eval SRC_DIRS :=) \
    $(eval include $(MODULE)/$(MODULE).mk) \
    ... \
)
```

where the `.mk` files are appending directory names to the `SRC_DIRS` variable, and after the inclusion, I am using the content of `SRC_DIRS` to collect source files and generate object files names, etc. CLion doesn't like this syntax. However, this works fine if I just invoke `make` on the command line.

Comment: Why do you have this line?  It seems not useful to write this when you could just write `include <filename>.mk` directly?  Please show us the part of the makefile where this line appears with relevant context (again, cut and paste text with formatting).

Comment: However, it's quite possible that clion's makefile parser can't understand this syntax; if so this would be an enhancement request you'd have to make to Jetbrains.  That's what you pay them for: there's nothing we can do about it here.

Comment: @MadScientist Edited the question to add the relevant context. It does look like this is an issue with the CLion parser.

Comment: It looks like it might be confused by the `:=)`.  One idea is to add a space after the `:=` before the close paren.  Another option is to use `define INCL`...`endef` to create a multi-line macro containing both the variable assignment and the `include`, then you could change the `foreach` to something like `$(foreach MODULE,$(MODULES),$(eval $(INCL)))` and that might work better.

Comment: Using a macro `define ... endef` addresses the issue.